# Broadly accepted term for a "thick wrapper"?

Tags: terminology

A wrapper is often explained as modification of an interface to another function with very little added functionality, if any.  I've seen scarce reference to a "thick wrapper" that does add nontrivial functionality.  Is there a broadly recognized term for a thick wrapper?

Comment: I think this depends a lot on what the "wrapper" does, I might say it "uses XYZ as an underlying API" or I might say it encapsulates XYZ.

Comment: Understood, but is there a noun meaning a wrapper that adds functionality on top of the function that is wrapped?

Comment: If someone wishes to downvote this question, I kindly ask for a (gentle) explanation of where the problem lies and how one might redress it.  Thanks.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but "what do I call this" questions never do very well here. To some extent, this is because it largely doesn't matter what you call something so long as the people you're talking to understand what you're talking about.

Comment: I agree that's the case in more common, general situations.  When trying to word IP protection succinctly, it's quite important.

Comment: "A wrapper is often explained as modification of an interface to another function with very little added functionality" - in OO terms, this is what's called an Adapter; there are other kinds of wrappers, though. I don't think there's a particular term that would encompass "non-Adapters". Adapters could also *restrict* available functionality (maybe you don't need all that a generic component provides). Another common type of wrapper is a Decorator - these preserve the interface so that you can *transparently add functionality* (that is, without affecting client code), and stack them together.

Comment: Thanks, Filip.  Pity that there isn't a succinct term for an adapter that restricts functionality to simplify the interface and then adds its own specialized functionality.

Comment: Without any further qualification on it, it sounds like you're simply describing a Layer.

Comment: Thanks, J_H.  I looked up the [definition of "layer"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_(object-oriented_design)) and though it may be technically correct, it is probably too targeted to developers for IP protection.  I could be wrong, but that's the sense I get being a non-expert in neither.

Comment: Wrappers are by definition thin. If it contains non-trivial functionality then it isn't a wrapper, it is an object in its own right (with a dependency), and should be named after what it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "wrapper" isn't perfect. If you need a better word that fits with object-oriented terms, look at different design patterns to find what fits your needs. Filip Milovanović's comment is prolly best here...

Comment: Thanks for accepting but I think Filip Milovanović' deserves the credit :)

Comment: Stack Exchange won't bookkeep this credit, but you did acknowledge him.  And you brought in the idea of looking at different design patterns.  Unfortunately, the audience for that kind of language is developers, whereas the language for IP protection needs to be for a more general audience (at least in my admittedly inexperienced opinion).

Comment: My challenge is that I am not a professional SW developer, so I would probably need to go to grad school to get a feel for the different design patterns.  And in the end, the target audience for IP protection documents aren't SW developers either.  I'll have to find a general-audience wording to describe the "layer" (a term that *J_H* kindly offered).